# Get rectangle within "spider net"?

Tags: geometry

Imagine circles of a given increasing radius around a center, crossed by lines of a given rotation -- how would I be able to draw an approximate 4-borders rectangle* inside one of the grid positions, as shown in the image, based on a point position in the image?

[image]

Details: I'm using Lua for a mobile app. The top left coordinate is 0, 0, so the center is maxX / 2, maxY / 2; I'm using the variables rotationStep and radiusStep to create the net.

*A 6-or-more-point polygon might look even better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First compute the four corners of the shape.

```
x1 = cx + radialScale*radiusStep*cos(rotationScale * rotationStep)
y1 = cy + radialScale*radiusStep*sin(rotationScale * rotationStep)
x2 = cx + radialScale*(radiusStep+1)*cos(rotationScale * rotationStep)
y2 = cy + radialScale*(radiusStep+1)*sin(rotationScale * rotationStep)

x3 = cx + radialScale*radiusStep*cos(rotationScale*(rotationStep+1))
y3 = cy + radialScale*radiusStep*sin(rotationScale*(rotationStep+1))
x4 = cx + radialScale*(radiusStep+1)*cos(rotationScale*(rotationStep+1))
y4 = cy + radialScale*(radiusStep+1)*sin(rotationScale*(rotationStep+1))
```

Where (cx, cy) is the center point - In your case (maxX/2, maxY/2).

The constants rotationScale and radialScale are just to scale up the steps to the full range. For example the rotationScale is 2PI/n if you have n sectors. And the radialScale is R/m if you have m "bands" and the outermost circle in the net has radius R. Hope that makes sense.

The idea here is just like in a regular grid.

- One starting point
- One point to "the right" (x+1 in a regular grid, rotationStep+1 here)
- One point "down2 (y+1 in a regular grid, radiusStep+1 here)
- And then one point right *and* down.

Now just draw the four lines between the points and voilá!

Most graphics packages also has a `DrawArc` method of sorts. This can be used to draw the two  circle arcs with very high performance while at the same time make it look even more pretty!

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the angle between center of the circles and the point specified.  Then find the 2 lines that have closes angles to it and it will be between these 2 lines.

Calculate the distance of your point from the circles center.

Plot the same distance along your lines (D), divide by the distance between circles.  You'll get all 4 points this way.

Comment: Well I already have the 2 lines, and I have the two circles, how do I get the 4 rectangle points now? Maybe in pseudocode? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have them?  Did you find the 2 lines and 2 circles that make the sector you are interested in?

Comment: Mk, yes I had this, but I am still not quite sure how to draw the rectangle (or 6+-point-polyline) from that. The circle I get by dividing the point position by the radiusStep, the rotation I got by `math.ceil( math.ceil( ( math.atan( (app.center.y - point.y) / (app.center.x - point.x) ) * 180 ) / math.pi ) / app.rotationStep )`